# How to recover a 'lost' screen session?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

Somehow I managed to close a screen window without screen 'noticing' it, so the session is still flagged as `attached`. This prevents me from re-attaching to this session. What can I do?

```
me@iupr-serv8:~$ screen -r
There are several suitable screens on:
    25028.pts-19.XXX-serv8  (01/05/2012 07:15:34 PM)    (Attached)
    24658.pts-19.XXX-serv8  (01/05/2012 07:11:38 PM)    (Detached)
    24509.pts-19.XXX-serv8  (01/05/2012 07:10:00 PM)    (Detached)
    18676.pts-5.XXX-serv8   (01/02/2012 06:55:33 PM)    (Attached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
me@XXX-serv8:~$ screen -r 25028
There is a screen on:
    25028.pts-19.XXX-serv8  (01/05/2012 07:15:33 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 25028.
```

**[update]**

In the end I found out, that the session was not lost, but the ID of the first session is `0`. The second session than has the ID `1`.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try detaching it first with `screen -d`. If that doesn't work, you can try, in increasing order of *emphasis*,

```
   -d|-D [pid.tty.host]
        does  not  start screen, but detaches the elsewhere running screen session. It has the
        same effect as typing "C-a d" from screen's controlling terminal. -D is the equivalent
        to  the  power  detach key.  If no session can be detached, this option is ignored. In
        combination with the -r/-R option more powerful effects can be achieved:

   -d -r   Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.

   -d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.

   -d -RR  Reattach a session and if necessary detach or create it. Use the first  session  if
           more than one session is available.

   -D -r   Reattach a session. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.

   -D -R   Attach  here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach.
           If necessary detach and logout remotely first.  If it was not running create it and
           notify the user. This is the author's favorite.

   -D -RR  Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it.
```

Comment: the `-d -r` options together will force attach that session.

Comment: I always use `screen -x` so I can attach from multiple locations at once. Of course, if you accidentally close a window, it seems like `-d -r` is better just to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 8):

```
screen -r '1234.somescreensession'
```

There is a screen on:

1234.somescreensession (Attached)

There is no screen to be resumed matching 1234.somescreensession.

Here is a simple way to take back that screen session.

```
screen -D -r '1234.somescreensession'
```

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same problem after my ssh connection closed unexpectedly with the message `Write Failed: broken pipe` while I had a screen session attached. However, I could not get my screen session to reattach using any of the commands above. Note that I use the following version:

```
~> screen --version
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

Apparently, there was still an instance of `sshd` running, which kept me from detaching and reattaching the session. After identifying the `PID` of the appropriate instance of `sshd` and `kill`ing it I was able to reattach with `screen -r`.

---

Just for information: You will definitely find more than one `sshd` demon, one will correspond to your current login and another belonging to the stale `screen` session (indeed, there could be multiple other `sshd`s running belonging to multiple other `screen`s).

Comment: I had the same issue good call

Answer (score 4):

Some times the multiple screens are running in the background.

They can be resumed by:

```
screen -r [pid]
```

To get the screen, first run `screen -R`, then you will see all the running PIDs of screen, after that resume by `screen -r [pid]`.