# How to tell screen session to regenerate its socket?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

**Note:** the situation described here is completely different from [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28675/10618).

---

I have a couple of *still-attached* screen sessions, but `screen -list` produces

```
% screen -list
No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-jones.
```

I've tried to send `SIGCHLD` signals to the screen process, and I have also killed some of the shells running under them (in the hope that this would cause the kernel to send some signal to these processes).  The theory behind all this is that such signals would cause `screen` to re-create the appropriate sockets under `/tmp/uscreens`.  But none of these things worked.

Since the sessions are still attached, is there anything that I can do *within each session* to have it regenerate the appropriate sockets?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I did an update that changed the default `SCREENDIR` with several active sessions.  Like you, I couldn't convince it to regenerate the fifo (there's probably a bug report worth filing somewhere in this), so what I ended up doing was using [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) to transition everything relevant to a new session.  It's tedious, but allowed me to preserve my state (as well as learn a bit).  Here are the steps I used; this can probably be streamlined or scripted:

1. Find the screen PID you want to transition, and get its list of child processes (I used `pstree -ps $PID`)
2. For each child process, get its PID and...

   - If it's a shell...

     - with nothing else running, `reptyr $PID`
     - with a normal process running in it, SIGTSTP it (^z or `kill -TSTP $PID`), `bg` it, `disown $PID` it, and `reptyr $PID; fg`.
   - If there's a process with [children](https://blog.nelhage.com/2014/08/new-reptyr-feature-tty-stealing/), `reptyr -T $PID`
   - If there's a normal process, `reptyr $PID`

This may not be foolproof, and I ended up with shells-in-shells and stuff like that, but it could be worse.